# Forma de instalar extension para GPU en tensorflow windows 8.1

Tags: docker, tensorflow

Queria saber de que manera puedo instalar nvidia-docker en windows,ya que en su documentación , solo tiene soporte para linux , si hay una guia por ahí que no he encontrado.
https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Installation

Comment: No comprendo la pregunta. ¿Será que quisiste decir "ya que en su documentación sólo tiene soporte para Linux"?

Comment: tienes razón , ya lo corregí.

Comment: ¿Quieres utilizar el plugin para armar contenedores con tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, al momento no es posible instalar `nvidia-docker` en Windows.

El plugin no soporta Windows, que necesitan soporte de pasarela de GPU (GPU passthrough) que sólo está disponible al momento en Windows 2016 Server y [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) sólo funciona sólo en algunas versiones de Windows 10 (ver [requisitos](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/#/docker-for-windows)).

Para hacerlo desde una máquina virtual, es decir tener un `guest` con Docker, necesitaría que el programa de virtualización tenga para pasarela PCI (PCI passthrough), que de acuerdo a [este](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtualization_software#Other_features) artículo de Wikipedia no está disponible para `host` de Windows.

Notar que Docker Toolbox utiliza una Oracle Virtual Box.

Referencias adicionales:

- [nvidia-docker issue 197](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/197)
- [nvidia-docker issue 43](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/43)